# Ubuntu20.04LTS no network, while 21.04 has no problem(B550 Unify)

Tags: drivers, 20.04

Both my wireless and wired network card cannot be recongnized by Ubuntu20.04LTS, but there isn't any problem in Ubuntu21.04 which should be more unstable, that's weird!

(Motherboard: MSI B550 Unify )

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: I just wonder how can I get a correct network in 20.04

Comment: I would say this is not a question let alone a real problem. Update to 21.04 and you're good to go. And BTW how do you know that it works in 21.04 if you're supposedly using 20.04?

Comment: Because I tried both version on my computer)

Comment: By the way, after I read the manual of 20.04 & 21.04 carefully, it seems that I'v known the reason... It seems due to the network driver of B550Unify is too new for 20.04, Ubuntu had not add support to this driver untill 21.04

Comment: Thank you all the same